# How do I add new column in BigQuerry table with values as CURRENT_DATETIME

Tags: sql, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

So I have a table as **tbl1** .and I need to add a new column **col1** with values as **current_datetime** .I have searched but was not able to find the answers .

***second question*** : is there any way where we can make a column with date as datatype and it  updates only when new data rolls into that table  so that we know when was the new data rolled up ?

Comment: You can use column with default value. If you don't set the value, the value is set automatically, like current date. But it work only for new rows, not for updates.

Comment: As mentioned by Guillaume, you might like to consider BigQuery default column values - see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/default-values  If you would like to populate retrospectively - you might need to do some data handling/migration activities, for example - copy the original table, drop the original table, create a new table, migrate data with the proper values for the new column, etc. As for updates in BigQuery, personally I would seriously consider data in BigQuery as immutable, and would never update it, only append new rows. But it up to you.

Comment: Thank you  
guillaume blaquiere and 
al-dann .